# Unable to switch to main branch in git

Tags: git

Whenever I try to switch to main branch this happens.
`$ git checkout main error: pathspec 'main' did not match any file(s) known to git`

what should I do?switch doesn't work as well.
`$ git switch main fatal: invalid reference: main`

I've  `git reset --hard`,but it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe you don't have branch named `main`? (Maybe you have one called `master`?) Try `git branch --all` to see what branches you do have.

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

- `git fetch origin main:main`
- `git checkout main`